# How to configure Jenkins Job to use Bitbucket Repository Access Key when cloning repo?

Tags: ssh, jenkins, bitbucket

In one of my bitbucket repositories on a Bitbucket server instance, I've configured an Access Key and would like to use this access key within a Jenkins Job to clone said repository. However, there doesn't seem to be a credential provider for this scenario.

I can't use the username with SSH key since with the access key associated with a system, doesn't have a username.

Can somebody point me in the right direction?

Thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just ignore the username; add your access key as an SSH key credential in Jenkins and put whatever you want in the username field.  When you clone a Bitbucket repository using SSH keys you almost always use `git` as the username anyway.

For instance, here is an example Pipeline that will check out a repo using an access key with the ID `myAccessKey`:

```
git(credentialsId: 'myAccessKey', url: 'ssh://git@bitbucket.my.org:7999/project/repo.git')
```

As you should be able to see, it doesn't matter what you put for the username field in your Jenkins SSH credential, because you checkout the repo as the `git` user regardless.

Alternatively, put `git` for the username when creating your credential.